# GET Request после нажатия кнопки

Tags: request, get

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла такая проблема, хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, передавался GET запрос.

тоесть:

```
<button style="width:45px" onclick="script() { $("GET ip_adress/rem/t1"); }">GET</button>

<button style="width:45px" onclick="script() { $("GET ./rem/t1"); }">GET</button>
```

данный пример не правильный... помогите правильно написать

Comment: @Insider, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А в чем проблема ссылкой сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если подразумевается асинхронный запрос то вот так - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: ну в общем, у меня уже есть jq, просто кнопка должна посылать запрос без ajax и тд

Comment: @Insider ну так оберните ее в форму.

   <form method="GET" action="rem/t1"><button>GET</button></form>

Comment: спасибо работает, а теперь, как сделать чтобы запрос был, но не переходил по новой ссылки
onclick="return false" не работает

Answer (score 1):

GET-запрос - это простой переход по ссылке. Можно сделать обычную ссылку и в css сделать ее похожей на кнопку. В вашем же случае можно сделать так

```
<button onclick="window.location='ваш_url';">Текст</button>
```